# Why does CTRL-C no longer stop my nginx container anymore?

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

I am experimenting with a nginx-based Dockerfile. The last line currently looks like this:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
... # not really relevant
CMD /bin/sh -c "envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/site.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

Now when I run the container with `docker run my-nginx-image`, I noticed that `CTRL-C` is no longer stopping the container.

Before that change, I had the following `CMD` statement in the end:

```
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Here, `CTRL-C` worked as expected: the container was stopped. Why is that? How can I have the both of two worlds?

- `CTRL-C` working
- `envsubst` included

**update**

After some reading, I realized that I have to bootstrap with `CMD [...]`. But I fail to integrate the whole command `envsubst < ... > ... && nginx -g 'daemon off;'` into the `[...]` syntax.

Comment: did you try `docker run -it my-nginx-image`?

Comment: No, not yet. I am mainly interested how to get the `CMD [...]` syntax working whith `envsubst` included. I think that will solve my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-run-cannot-be-killed-with-ctrl-c/13108/2

> So there are two factors at play here:
>
> If you specify a string for an entrypoint, like this:
>
> ENTRYPOINT /go/bin/myapp
>
> Docker runs the script with /bin/sh -c 'command'. This intermediate
>   script gets the SIGTERM, but doesn’t send it to the running server
>   app.
>
> To avoid the intermediate layer, specify your entrypoint as an array
>   of strings.
>
> ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/myapp"]

Comment: I tried doing that, but I failed to figure out the syntax of integrating the `envsubst < ... > ... && nginx ...` into the `[ ... ]` syntax. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Create a shell script docker-entrypoint.sh with your command and add this script to docker image. and in CMD just run this script.
Don't forget to chmod a+x... something like
ADD docker-entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod a+x /docker-entrypoint.sh
CMD ["/ /docker-entrypoint.sh"]

Comment: @Mosei If that `docker-entrypoint.sh` spwans another process (such as `nginx -g 'daemon off;'`, will signals also be forwarded to that process?

Comment: I asked it on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681357/will-the-application-run-as-pid-1-and-will-signals-be-received-if-we-bootstrap-i so comments will not be cluttered.