# Will the application run as PID 1 and will signals be received if we bootstrap it in a entrypoint.sh?

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

It's good practice to start the service with

```
CMD ["/go/bin/myapp"]
```

instead of

```
CMD /go/bin/myapp
```

In the first way, SIGTERMs are caught by the applicaiton, while in the second way, they are caught by the underlying `/bin/sh` script, which does not forward them to the service. I learned this from https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-run-cannot-be-killed-with-ctrl-c/13108/2.

Now I am wondering if `CMD ["..."]` is completely equivalent to putting `...` in an `/entrypoint.sh` script and calling `CMD ["/entrypoint.sh"]`? Will now child applications also be running as PID 1 and therefore receive all signals?

As a concrete example, I want to create a script with:

```
envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/site.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
&&
nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

And call `CMD ["/entrypoint.sh"]` at the end of my `Dockerfile`. Is this safe and will nginx run as PID 1 despite that there are multiple commands (`envsubst` and `ngingx`) in the script?

This matter confuses me and I am trying to figure out when and when not to use `tini` (https://github.com/krallin/tini).

Answer (score 3):

Here is my try to follow what also the MySQL 5.7 [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/tree/master/5.7) does... but with an Nginx image.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"] 
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**docker-entrypoint.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo "preparing..."

exec "$@"
```

The idea is to do anything needed as a preparation inside the `docker-entrypoint.sh` script and with `exec "$@"` you then pass the signals to the `CMD`. (This means that you will have to use `envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/site.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` inside `docker-entrypoint.sh`)

---

Link of relevant example to `Dockerfile` docs: [*If you need to write a starter script for a single executable, you can ensure that the final executable receives the Unix signals by using `exec` and `gosu` commands...*](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example)

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [tini GitHub page](https://github.com/krallin/t):

> If you are using Docker 1.13 or greater, Tini is included in Docker
>   itself. This includes all versions of Docker CE. To enable Tini, just
>   pass the --init flag to docker run.

Or you can you use [minit](https://github.com/chazomaticus/minit).  It runs /etc/minit/startup on container startup and /etc/minit/shutdown when a container is stopped.  I usually use this piece of code as entrypoint:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -gt 0 ] ; then
        exec "$@"
else
        exec /sbin/minit
fi
```